# Meaning of ‘silvan game’

Tags: meaning, poetry

Does anybody know the meaning of italicized phrase?

> Fye upon your name!
>   In wrath, for loss of *silvan game*,
>   Saint Hilda’s priest ye slew.

It's passage from Walter Scott's Marmion, [Canto Second](http://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/scott/walter/marmion/canto2.html#canto2). Something about ‘silvan’ I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvan), however the phrase ‘silvan game’ still makes no sense for me.

> Then Whitby’s nuns exulting told,
>   How to their house three Barons bold
>   Must menial service do;
>   While horns blow out a note of shame,
>   And monks cry ‘Fye upon your name!
>   In wrath, for loss of *silvan game*,
>   Saint Hilda’s priest ye slew.’—
>   ‘This, on Ascension-day, each year,
>   While labouring on our harbour-pier,
>   Must Herbert, Bruce, and Percy hear.’

This is whole text of complete thought, but it brings nothing useful, I think.

Thanks.

Comment: Being a Pennsylvanian, I thought I'd mention that my state's name means literally, "[William] Penn's woods."  (My mention, though only tangentially relevant, is free!)

Comment: An interesting aside: this poem is the source of the famous quotation - 'Oh, what a tangled web we weave,
When first we practise to deceive!'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting poetry

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well in its original form, I believe it was not OT, since it was basically concerned with which definition of *game* was in use. When more context was provided, the question was effectively broadened to be about interpretation within the broader context of the poem (and potentially its historical context as well). This might have made it OT, though I don't think that was really the intent of the edit.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I would say if OP doesn't know the ***game** = wild animals hunted for food* sense, he probably shouldn't be reading Walter Scott in the first place. I think it's General Reference anyway.

Comment: Articles seem to make "no sense for" you either?

Comment: I think closing this one was a bit harsh. OP obviously did put some effort into looking up the meaning, and it's easy to see how the use of "loss" steered him to the wrong meaning of "game". Also, I'd say it's more about poetry comprehension than interpretation, so I don't think it's off topic on that measure either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the passage you quote, the "silvan game" in question is a wild boar.

[As p.s.w.g. has already explained](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/119018/5836) "sylvan" refers to woods or forest, and "game" can refer to animals which are hunted.

The notes accompanying [the text you linked to](http://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/scott/walter/marmion/canto2.html) confirm this interpretation, and offer a fuller account of the story being told:

> Stanza XIII. line 234. Scott quotes from ‘A True Account,’ circulated
>   at Whitby, concerning the consequences of a boar-hunt on Eskdale-side,
>   belonging to the Abbot of Whitby. The boar, being hard pressed, made
>   for a hermitage and died just within the door. Coming up, the three
>   leaders — William de Bruce, Lord of Uglebarnby, Ralph de Percy, Lord
>   of Smeaton, and a freeholder named Allatson — in their disappointment
>   and wrath set upon the hermit, whom they fatally wounded. [...]

Answer (score 7):

*Silvan* (or *sylvan*) refers to a forest, while *game* in this sense most likely refers or an animal being hunted.

> **9.**
>      **a.** Wild animals, birds, or fish hunted for food or sport.
>      **b.** The flesh of these animals, eaten as food.
>
> —Source [theFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/game)

So the *silvan game* is some type of forest-dwelling animal being hunted.

Comment: Is there any point in killing priest because of failure to hunt an animal?

Comment: @mikeonly: Hunting was a major preoccupation of mediaeval nobility (the New Forest where I live is a large area originally cleared specifically so that the Norman kings could hunt deer). I don't know the legend, but it is not at all unlikely that a bishop should ban hunting in his woods, and a nobleman should be so incensed by this that he struck the bishop down and had to do penance every year thereafter.

Comment: @TimLymington that seems like a very good interpretation of this passage, but perhaps rather than the Bishop banning hunting in a particular wood, it was simply banned (along with other irreverent activities) on a given holy day (ascension day?). But I could be wrong.